# Highcharts categories months don't add

Tags: php, html, highcharts

I want to display the months from Jan - Dec, but the data in series are steady. What happened, is that the months that only display in charts are from Jan - May. How will I do it? Please see below code,

```
function getchart2()
{

$('#container2').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
                renderTo: 'container'
    },
title: {
            text: 'Daily Events',
            style: {
                'color': '#06F',
                'font-family': 'Roboto',
                'font-size': '16px',
                'font-weight': 'bold'

            },
            useHTML: true
        },
    xAxis: {

       categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'No. of Events'
        },

        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
  legend: {
            itemStyle: {

                'color': '#666',
                'font-family': 'Roboto',
                'font-weight': 'normal',
                'font-size': '11px'

            },

            useHTML: true
        },
     tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                this.x +': '+ this.y;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
        pointWidth: 30,
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                style: {
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }

            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
         name: 'Incoming',
        data: [
         {y: 10.4, color: '#FAA961'},  //incoming
          {y: 15.4, color: '#FAA961'}, 
          {y: 20.4, color: '#FAA961'}, 
          {y: 12.4, color: '#FAA961'}, 
          {y: 30.4, color: '#FAA961'}, 
        ],
        color: '#FAA961'
    }, {
        name: 'Ongoing',
        data: [
         {y: 10.4, color: '#438EF7'},  //incoming
          {y: 15.4, color: '#438EF7'}, 
          {y: 20.4, color: '#438EF7'}, 
          {y: 12.4, color: '#438EF7'}, 
          {y: 30.4, color: '#438EF7'}, 
        ],
        color: '#438EF7'
    }, {
        name: 'Finished',
        data: [
         {y: 34.4, color: '#43F752'},  //incoming
          {y: 35.4, color: '#43F752'}, 
          {y: 40.4, color: '#43F752'}, 
          {y: 42.4, color: '#43F752'}, 
          {y: 20.4, color: '#43F752'}, 
        ],
        color: '#43F752'
    }]
});

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts Categories don't add](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174196/highcharts-categories-dont-add)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this would be same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174196/highcharts-categories-dont-add).

You only need to change the 'max' value to 11.